# How do you query ubuntu 20.04 to list computer devices, especially wifi card, in a dell inspiron 1420?

Tags: networking, drivers, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 1420 with Vista installed. I did a clean install of Linux Ubuntu ver. 20.04 which wiped Vista upon install. Upon first boot system runs well with the exception: in settings no WiFi routers are listed. My assumption is that Ubuntu didn't find a driver for the WiFi card, which may be a Conexant RD02-D330 card, (from bottom of computer?). I there a known driver?

Is there a command in Ubuntu that lists hardware specifics such as hard drives, WiFi cards, etc., and the parameters for operation?

I'm new to Linux, so I need Linux answers for dummies.

Comment: Open "Software & Updates" and look for Additional Drivers. Are there any?

Answer (score 0):

For me `inxi-F` is the best readable and understandable display of the hardware currently used. The commands can be be executed in the terminal. If a device does not turn up, either `dmesg` or  `lspci -vvv` might give you a hint.

Comment: Thank you, i'll give that a try.

Comment: Thank you kanehekill, I have output from the command lspci -vvv as follows but it means nothing to me, can you interpret? Ops, I don't know how to show screenshot jpg.

Comment: You copy and paste it - you don't make screenshots from terminals. However your question has been closed -due to the lack of investigation. Ask again, if you don't find any solutions on the board. Don't be annoyed - we're getting many questions that already have been answered. To avoid duplicates we close them.

Comment: K, not annoyed but frustrated!

Comment: Yes, understandable. But your infos may be incorrect. Look [here](https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/dell/laptops-desktops/inspiron-1420/1242) and try to find out your "real" wifi hardware. (Conexant seems to be a modem, not wifi). If you found your driver try to find out (by searching here) how to install that driver. Note that you might be out of luck: Many drivers have been reversed engineered  since the manufacturer will not provide  neither information nor drivers for linux - but not all. If you cant find an installation instruction, ask a question like: "How to install driver xyz"

Comment: BTW - just by searching "Dell Inspiron 1420 wifi" I got directed to [this] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). So you've got a broadcom wifi... I'm sure you'll get the gist.